# How to Disable download missing package each time in meteor?

Tags: meteor, npm

I tried to create meteor web application, but meteor **download missing package each time** when I change my code, and it was unnecessary.

So, can I config it only runs at the first time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the actual message on the package it tries to download? Anyway, there are two potential locations where meteor looks for packages that need to be installed.

1. This is which each Meteor application and it's using Meteor Atmosphere packages. You can find these at `.meteor` folder in your project root file called `packages` path `./meteor/packages`

Other potential place is `packages.json` in project root. It exists if you have used `npm install` or `meteor npm install` within the project.

Deleting unnecessary packages from these files should do the trick.